# Integrating serenity/thucidydes with spock

Tags: automation, phantomjs, spock, serenity-bdd, spock-reports

I am working on automation tests with selenium webdriver and spock framework. I would like to know how can I integrate serenity with spock testing?
My project is build with gradle and groovy is the language used for writing tests. Any sample class files or links will be appreciated.

Thanks,
RV

Answer (score 3):

Have you already checked out geb? (http://gebish.org/)
Geb is the right webdriver abstraction layer to be used with spock.

Comment: Yes but I am looking for the comprehensive reporting that serenity provides. I have worked with serenity and cucumber but was wondering if the same is available in spock

Comment: you can create comprehensive reporting with spock and the spock-reports plugin by renato athaydes. Whoever, afaik, there is nit such a template out of the box. You have to create your own.

Comment: But this does not give me a pie chart like in cucumber/serenity reports, does it?

Comment: If you gather the data within the template and use a javascript library or something like google charts to render it.... Geb is a really great tool, but I do understand the reporting needs and it is not too easy to create a report template... :-( Maybe I should create one when I get around to it...